# How to insert parent and child record in talend?

Tags: talend

I have a scenario where i need to insert parent table followed by child table where the parent table id is set as foreign key in child table.
example:
Insert records to student table after that i need to insert marks for the students in child table. This has to happen in a sequence and in single job.

Answer (score 0):

you have to insert all the records in the parent table first and post committing this table you should go to the loading of child tables records.
The main thing is to commit the parent table after its loading so that it should not violate parent child relations.
Get back to me if it is done or any clarification is required.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my scenario, I have to do inserting parent and child in single batch. The source has values for parent and child as single row. So i need to map the data for parent as well as for child. Hence i have to do in single batch. I tried with LastInsertId but no luck.

Comment: Can you please give a sample data which is present in the source and the corresponding target tables you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can split this in two jobs and have a master job for orchestration.
Here's what I suggest. Create a master job that has two tRunJobs (one that loads parent and one that loads child). The parent job will populate the parent table with the incoming data but will also pass the data to the master job from tBufferOutput component. This data will be fed to the next job (that loads the child table). 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, students general data (parent) and students marks (child) you could do :

- **if both tables have autoincrement id** : after insertion in parent use a column like studentID (from the input) as lookup key for the child insertion

  - 1st subjob has tuniq to get the repeated general data once and tfilter (or tmap) to get only wanted columns
  - 2nd subjob is obvious (lookup with key that exist in source, if not see below)

[overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unzi5.png)

- **if no column in source can be an ID** : here's some ideas ...

use ETL concept of loading in a tmp file with a localy generated ID

```
Numeric.sequence("sequence1",1,1)
```

or get lastID from DataBase with tMysqlLastInsertId as lookup in the 2nd tMap

Obviously if your scenario is different, please send the specifics

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is no unique id in source so i will try to do as per your suggestion, insert in temp table with auto increment id and then  insert into destination table.